# How to create an ordered list of matches from multiple Regexps in a string?

Tags: ruby, regex

How can one get a list of matches in a string from multiple different Regexps, and have these matches ordered relatively by their position in the string?

The string can contain multiple matches from the same Regexp.

---

**Based on sepp2k's answer, here's the solution I implemented (simplified example):**

```
test_data = "
  a_word
  another_word  
  23445
  12432423
  third_word
"

regexps = /(?<word>[a-zA-Z_]+)/, /(?<number>[\d]+)/
words = regexps.map{|re| re.names}.flatten!

matches = []
test_data.scan(Regexp.union(regexps)) do
  words.each do |word|
    m = Regexp.last_match
    matches << {word => m.to_s} if m[word]
  end
end

p matches
```

This outputs:

```
[{"word"=>"a_word"}, {"word"=>"another_word"}, {"number"=>"23445"}, {"number"=>"12432423"}, {"word"=>"third_word"}]
```

Comment: What do you want to do if more than one regex match the same substring or different substrings starting at the same position?

Comment: Example data and expected output would be nice.

Comment: By position do you mean order or index into the string?

Comment: @sawa: in my case I don't think I'll run into that edge case, but if it happens, I suppose the smallest match first. And if they are the same size then so be it.

Comment: @Mark Thomas: Thanks for asking. I've added an example, and also the implementation I came up with. Let me know if/how this code can be improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Regexp.union` to turn all the regexps into one regexp and then use `String#scan` to find all matches. The array returned by `scan` will be ordered by the position of the match.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I've posted an implementation of your suggestion. Let me know if/how this code can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

That seems awfully complex when `inject` and a `case` statement will do IMHO:

```
> %w{a_word another_word 23445 12432423 third_word}.inject([]) {|s,v| s << case v when /^[a-zA-Z_]+$/ then {'word' => v} when /^\d+$/ then {'number' => v} end }
=> [{"word"=>"a_word"}, {"word"=>"another_word"}, {"number"=>"23445"}, {"number"=>"12432423"}, {"word"=>"third_word"}]
```

For readability you could have the following:

```
data = <<EOD
  a_word
  another_word
  23445
  12432423
  third_word
EOD

data.split.inject([]) do |s,v|
  s << case v
  when /^[a-zA-Z_]+$/
    {'word' => v}
  when /^\d+$/
    {'number' => v}
  end
end
```